# How can I change the width of a separator inside an UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, ios8

It is possible to change the width of the separators of the cells inside an `UITableView`?

I successfully changed the color of the separators but I don't find where to change their width.

Comment: Where is the downvote of this question?

Comment: Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

Comment: I thought this question isn't nothing like the exposed above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what "width" means to you. A cell or a table view has a `separatorInset` which might help. On the other hand, if you don't like the way the built-in separator is drawn, you can simply suppress the built-in separator and draw your own "separator" (e.g. some kind of line at the bottom) as part of the configuration of the cell.

Comment: I refer to the separators among cells. Regarding to your answer , not exist a better way to do it that draw my own separator?

Comment: Are you asking me to repeat what I already said? What I've told you, I've told you.

Comment: No @matt where I asking you if there are other ways to make this possible. Can you post some sample of your answer please if you don't mind?

Comment: No, I won't write your code for you. And in any case, how to draw is a separate question. If you don't know how to draw, learn. I answered the question you asked.

Comment: Yes you're right you have one answer, maybe there is a better one, for now your answer is not bad. One thing, I don't expect you write code for me, in some cases the sample code is for support the answer